# How check if a property was set in a struct

Tags: go

I am trying to find how check if a structure property was set, but i cannot find any way.

I expect something like this but of corse this not works:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    property    string
}

test := new(MyStruct)
if test.property {
    //do something with this
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like dyoo said, you can use `nil` if your struct properties are pointers. If you want to keep them as strings you can compare with `""`. Here is a sample:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    Property string
}

func main() {
    s1 := MyStruct{
        Property: "hey",
    }

    s2 := MyStruct{}

    if s1.Property != "" {
        fmt.Println("s1.Property has been set")
    }

    if s2.Property == "" {
        fmt.Println("s2.Property has not been set")
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/YStKFuekeZ

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could include the code samples in your answer rather than completely rely on an external service like golang play which might move to some other place.

Comment: What happen if it is a bool and not a string? and I do not want to use *bool

Comment: Think about what you want: A bool with three possible values: true, false, and unset. That’s exactly what *bool allows for.

Answer (score 13):

You can use pointers and their `nil` value to determine whether something has been set or not.  For example, if you change your structure to

```
type MyStruct struct {
    property *string
}
```

then `property` can either be pointing to a string value, in which case it was set, or it can be `nil`, in which case it hasn't been set yet.  This is an approach that the protobuf library uses to determine whether fields are set or not, as you can see in https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/source/browse/README#83

Comment: Yep i know this, but i cannot change it to a reference because is used by https://code.google.com/p/gcfg/ lib, thanks anyway

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Charlie's answer and to (sort of) answer asafel's question, if the property's type isn't string, you can check the default value assign by Go to that particular type like this:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    Str  string
    Bool bool
    Int  int
    Uint uint
}

func main() {
    s := MyStruct{}

    fmt.Println(s.Str)
    fmt.Println(s.Bool)
    fmt.Println(s.Int)
    fmt.Println(s.Uint)

}
```

Output:

```
""
false
0
0
```

And you can check whether the value "*is set*" in a struct or not

```golang
if (s.Bool == false) {
    fmt.Println("Bool is either set to false, or wasn't set");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fNigWCb_2fg)

Well as you might have noticed, you can't technically really check whether the property was set or not, but I think this is a worth addition to Charlie's answer

Answer (score -17):

Another way to do it would be to make the value private and use a get/set method on it. a bool can determine if set or not.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    isPropertySet bool
    property string
}

func (my *MyStruct) SetProperty(val string) {
    my.property = val
    my.isPropertySet = true
}

func (my *MyStruct) IsPropertySet() bool {
    return my.isPropertySet
}
```

Comment: This not only adds complexity but also wastes memory. If you absolutely want to have an `IsSet` function you should check for the `nil` value of the type in that function.